# reading cross site iframe location

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I need to only read the location of an iframe that loads different domain.
I dont want to change it; I only want to know where the location is.
The XSS protection prevents me to read `location.host`

Can I get the iframe's location in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless you can inject your own script into the iframe.  The browser's same-domain policy prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the parent URL of an iframe, try using `document.referrer`